# Em Python 2 é mais performático usar range ou xrange?

Tags: python

A linguagem de programação que mais utilizo é PHP <del>:(</del> e, depois que foi implementado *Generators* na versão 5.5, dizem ser mais rápido utilizar ele para geração de números em sequência do que com a função `range` - que cria um `array` com a sequência, ao contrário do *Generator*, que poderia gerar um número de cada vez pelo `yield`.

Exemplo `range` PHP:

```
range(1, 1000); // Retorna: [1, 2, 3, ..., 1000]
```

Exemplo *Generator* PHP:

```
function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    if ($start < $limit) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be +ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be -ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}
```

A saída seria:

```
xrange(); // Generator(object)
```

De acordo com o pessoal do PHP, numa geração de sequência numérica com `range` em PHP com *1000000* utilizaria mais de *100MB* de memória, ao passo que com um `Iterator` que fizesse a mesma coisa, gastaria *1kb* na memória.

## Python

Com base nisso, percebi que no Python as sequências geradas por `range` são listas, diferente da versão *3*, que retorna um objeto `Range`.

Também no Python há uma função chamada `xrange` (que é imitada pelo PHP nessa [página](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.generators.overview.php)), que retorna um `Generator`.

**A questão é**: O fato de `range` no Python retornar uma lista não tornaria essa função mais custosa, quanto a memória, por causa do `list` que é gerado?

Se eu quiser fazer um `range` de *1* a *1000*, em Python, seria mais aconselhável usar `xrange`, ou o próprio `range` não faria mal ao consumo de memória?

Comment: -1 por comparar python com php :P. A pergunta é sobre python e tem a tag do php ta certo isso? o -1 era zoeira, +1

Comment: @rray é o "vício de linguagem". Alguém percebeu o trocadilho? Bem, a intenção era colocar Python mesmo, value ;)

Comment: Sobre o php: Olhando alguns exemplos, nem em todos casos foi mais rapido, houve casos que foram o contrário, mas em consumo de memoria é que foi a grande vantagem para o php. Um `range(0, 1000000)` pode resultar em um consumo de mais de 100mb de memória o.0 ... Já com generator será alguns kb.

Comment: Acho as versões recentes de Python já implementam range() como xrange() e a diferença de performance já não existe.

Answer (score 6):

Como você levantou, a função `range(x, y)` cria uma lista de elementos de *x* a *y*.

A função `xrange(x,y)` gera cada elemento individualmente, e isto sim, economiza memória e tempo de *startup*.

Lembrando que no caso de *1000* elementos, a queda na performance seria quase imperceptível. Mas em proporções maiores poderia sim levar a uma baixa na performance do computador por consumo exagerado de memória.

A performance de `range()` é pior, e o motivo é simples, quando você usa por exemplo a função assim:

```
for x in range(0, 1000000000):
    print x
```

A função cria uma lista de *1* bilhão de elementos e aloca ela na memória.

Ao passo que com a função `xrange()`:

```
for x in xrange(0,1000000000):
    print x
```

A função gera os elementos uma unica vez economizando memória e tempo de execução.