# Como verificar se um número está dentro de um intervalo no Python?

Tags: python, comparação, inteiros

No Python, gostaria de verificar se um número está dentro de um intervalo.

Existe uma maneira mais pythônica do que o seguinte código?

```
if n >= 100 and n <= 200:
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a seguinte sintaxe:

```
if 100 <= n <= 2000:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra alternativa, porém limitada dependendo do que for verificar é o [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
numero = 101

if numero in range(100, 200):
    print ("{} está no intervalo!".format(numero))
else:
    print ("{} não consta no intervalo!".format(numero))
```

**Nota**: No Python *2.x* use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) ao invés de `range`.

Mais informações: [**Em Python 2 é mais performático usar `range` ou `xrange`?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104565/6454)

Como [mencionado pelo jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148843/como-verificar-se-um-n%C3%BAmero-est%C3%A1-dentro-de-um-intervalo-no-python/148856?noredirect=1#comment307554_148856), o `range` não funciona adequadamente quando usado números de [ponto flutuante](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), como alternativa, pode-se usar [*expressões*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html):

```
def xfrange(start, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = float(start)
        start = 0.0

    if step is None:
        step = 1.0

    cur = float(start)

    while cur < stop:
        yield cur
        cur += step
```

<kbd>[**Fonte**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66472/#c6)</kbd>

Mais informações: [**Para que serve o `yield`?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/6454)

Exemplo de uso:

```
if 5.5 in xfrange(0, 6.5, 0.5):
    print ("{} está no intervalo!".format(numero))
else:
    print ("{} não está no intervalo!".format(numero))
```

O exemplo acima verifica se *5.5* está dentro do intervalo de *0* a *6.5*, de *0.5* em *0.5* por vez.

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/Crmu)</kbd>

Uma segunda alternativa usando [métodos mágicos](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html):

```
def inRange(inicio, final, n):
    try:
        return (inicio).__le__(n).__and__((final).__ge__(n))
    except:
        return None
```

A função acima verifica se `n` é [menor ou igual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=__le__#operator.__le__) a *inicio* e se *final* é  [maior ou igual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=__le__#operator.__ge__) a `n`.

Exemplo de uso:

```
print (inRange(1, 10, 5))      # True  "5 >= 1 e 5 <= 10"
print (inRange(0.5, 5.0, 5.1)) # False "5.1 >= 0.5 e 5.1 > 5.0" 
print (inRange(0.4, 1.0, 0.6)) # True  "0.6 >= 0.4 e 0.6 <= 1.0"
print (inRange(0.1, 0.3, 0.4)) # False "0.4 >= 0.1 e 0.4 > 0.3"
print (inRange(0, 100, 55))    # True  "55 >= 0 e 55 <= 100"
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/CrkZ)</kbd>

Essas são algumas alternativas, use aquilo que for mais adequado e simples, como tal sugerido na [resposta do Fabio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148844/6454).

Comment: Importante notar que esta alternativa verifica se 100 <= n < 200 e não 100 <= n <= 200. Além disso, esta solução só funciona para inteiros, visto que o Python irá verificar se `numero` está presente na **lista** `intervalo`.

Comment: Essa não é uma boa forma - se ofr em Python 3, e o seu número for sempre um inteiro, ela funciona bem - se for em Python2, em que o range devolve uma lista, a performance será sofrível - e de quaquer forma, se for um número float, o resultado vai ser sempre falso.

Esse é um bom exemplo de como *não* fazer.

Comment: @jsbueno Já editei a resposta e deixei claro isso...

Comment: @downvoter motivo??

Comment: O downvoter era eu - com as edições novas, está ok.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a forma mais correta é a que tu descreveste:

```
if n >= 100 and n <= 200:
```

A meu ver a forma:

```
if n in range(100, 201):
```

Irá consumir mais recursos de forma desnecessária uma vez que irá criar uma lista de 100 valores e irá compará-los 1 a 1.

No entanto uma forma ligeiramente mais elegante seria:

```
if 100 <= n <= 200:
```